# How to set auto-filter in poi-3.2

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I try to set auto-filter using apache-poi.

I found some method using below code:

`sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("B1"));`

but my poi version is 3.2, so I can't use this method.

Is there any other way to set auto-filter using apache-poi-3.2?

Comment: Is there a reason for you not to update your version of apache poi? If you are using maven or gradle, you won't have to do very much to update it.

Comment: because my company still use old version of java(1.7). so I only can use old version of poi(need < 4.0)

Comment: POI 3.17 supports Java 7 (much newer release)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try saving the first and the last cell from filter area.
Then do the following:

```
sheet.setAutoFilter(new CellRangeAddress(firstCell.getRowIndex(), lastCell.getRowIndex(), firstCell.getColumnIndex(), lastCell.getColumnIndex()));
```

Comment: I get this error:
The method setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress) is undefined for the type HSSFSheet.  

It's weird that I found this method in apache POI document, but In poi-3.2-FINAL.jar, org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet doesn't have this method